# Base Workflow Class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to have some kind of base class for a workflow (It is a Sharepoint 2010 workflow, but the question is about the workflow foundation in general)? I would like to have some basic methods which I will use in all my workflows (Something like a helper class).

In the VS Designer I have seen the property "Base Class" which is System.Workflow.Activities.StateMachineWorkflowActivity. I already tried to create my base class deriving from this class, but I cannot select it as a base class in my derived Workflows. The type selection box queries for "types which derive from Activity" and as my base class derives from StateMachineWorkflowActivity it cannot find it of course.

Is there any way (besides just creating a class holding all my helper methods) to derive all my workflows from a "common workflow"? I'm looking for something like this:

```
public class BaseWorkflow : StateMachineWorkflowActivity
{
    // code here
}

public partial class CustomWorkflow : BaseWorkflow
{
    // code here
}
```

What are the problems with this approach? Serialization?